# Can two cols of a csv file be concatenated with string in Shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a file in below format :
inputfile.csv
id,flag
1,Y
2,N
3,Y

and a variable as

```
key="x2"
```

I want a shell script which can give output file as :

```
output.csv
id,flag,file_nm
1,Y,1_x2.pdf
2,N,UNK
3,Y,3_x2.pdf
```

so basically here I want is file_nm , if flag=Y then file_nm = $id"_"$key".pdf

I tried awk command as below in .sh or shell script

```
key="x2" ## key can change
awk -F"," 'NR==1{$3="PDF_FILE_NM";print;next} $2 == "Y" {$3=$1"_"$key".pdf"}; $2 == "N" {$3="UNK"}1' OFS="," ./inputfile.csv > ouput.csv
```

But this does not work and gives me weird output.
I am not good in unix whatever code is given here is by research only.

thanking in advance

Comment: Question (close to) well formated, with your attempts. Just need better code blocks. Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) Upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, using any `awk`:

```
awk -v suf=x2.pdf 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2=="Y"{$3=NR"_"suf} $2=="N"{$3="UNK"} 1' file
```

```
1,Y,1_x2.pdf
2,N,UNK
3,Y,3_x2.pdf
```